# How should I fix my runTime method to both subtract from my timeLeft variable/ return remaining time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Sup, I am completely new to stackOverflow and I started to learn how to do C# during my class. For my final project, I'm doing a reaction game where you have to press the key t as fast as possible before the timer. However, one major issue came up. I tried using a timer method and had a variable inside of it called timeLeft. What I want to happen is that as soon as the user presses t, the time stops and it shows you the remaining time. However what I get instead is that no matter what, the computer doesn't take the key and tells you that you ran out of time. I didn't know where else to put this question in, but I felt like this is a good spot. The project is made in C# and with visual studio. My code is below, and if there is anything i should change or do for this project, let me know. Thank you!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string starter;
    ConsoleKeyInfo stopper;
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to REFLEX. Check how fast are those hands?");
    Console.WriteLine("When you are ready to start, type start");
    starter = Console.ReadLine();

    if (starter.ToLower() == "start")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Go");
        Console.WriteLine("Press t to stop timer!");
        stopper = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine(RunTimer(stopper));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("what are you doing? You have one more chance, otherwise restart");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to REFLEX. Check how fast are those hands?");
        Console.WriteLine("When you are ready to start, type start");
        starter = Console.ReadLine();

        if (starter.ToLower() == "start")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Go");
            Console.WriteLine("Press t to stop timer!");
            stopper = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(RunTimer(stopper));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That's it, no more!");
        }
    }
}

static string RunTimer(ConsoleKeyInfo stopper)
{
    int timeLeft;

    for (timeLeft = 450000000; timeLeft > 0; timeLeft--)
    {
        while (stopper.Key != ConsoleKey.T)
        {
            do
            {
                stopper = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(RunTimer(stopper));
            }
            while (timeLeft > 0);
        }
    }
    if (timeLeft == 0)
    {
        return "Sorry, you ran out of time, try again!";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Congrats you won. You had " + timeLeft + " milseconds left";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you, it will block until a key is pressed at Console.ReadKey, if you wanted to overcome this you would need to make it multithreaded but thats likely a problem for another day.

```
        static string RunTimer()
        {
            int maxTime = 450000000;
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed;
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            do
            {
                keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
            }
            while (stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds < maxTime && keyPressed.Key != ConsoleKey.T);

            stopwatch.Stop();

            if (stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds < maxTime)
            {
                return "Sorry, you ran out of time, try again!";
            }
            else
            {
                int timeLeft = maxTime - stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
                return "Congrats you won. You had " + timeLeft + " milseconds left";
            }
        }
```

To Use it change this

```
 if (starter.ToLower() == "start")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Go");
        Console.WriteLine("Press t to stop timer!");
        stopper = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine(RunTimer(stopper));
    }
```

to

```
 if (starter.ToLower() == "start")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Go");
        Console.WriteLine("Press t to stop timer!");
        Console.WriteLine(RunTimer());
    }
```